# What are some rarely-mentioned networking models/strategies?

Tags: networking, multiplayer

I've been thinking about multiplayer and networking a lot lately, and I've found oodles of information, but I feel like there might be some standard models or strategies for networking that I haven't seen.

- There's the obvious client-server model, using the client as a terminal that sends keystrokes and recieves location information about the other entities.
- There's a point to point model, I believe - how two clients can play a game without the setup of a dedicated server (seen in LAN a lot).
- There's the client prediction strategy where the client is allowed to take control of the player while it waits for latency to bring back the server's actual position for the player - keeping a log of keystrokes to make the correction seem smooth.
- In cases where the servers are overloaded, I've seen a strategy that dedicates some of the work like AI to clients. I've seen it in the DayZ mod... Clients take control of some zombies when they get close.

Are there any glaringly obvious or rarely seen strategies or models, errors in the brief descriptions I've listed above, and/or additional reading into the deep parts of this topic?

Answer (score 1):

I think that no matter what strategy you plan to use, you need to consider methods like:

- KISS (Keep It Simple Stupid)
- DRY (Don't repeat your self)

Read books like:

- Clean code

Simple non repeated code tends to run clean and smooth, use alot of benchmark tests

Divide the system's node value with 20 and set a max time for execution, eg. first node max 200 ms, second node max 100 ms, third node 5 ms. etc. That way you get clean and fast code, i use this method with web services and most calls to the service is almost always less than 200 ms.

Comment: Not quite the answer I was looking for but some very useful and professional advice. Thanks for your response!

Comment: The point was that there is no right or wrong model here, as long as you keep repsonse time to a minimum. And another one, benchmark on the server you plan to run it on, a function on your own computer might take 2 seconds but 50 ms on the server.